# Issue designing bootstrap nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

We are designing a new website, and the designer has created the nav bar as follows, you can see the curve (this is what I'm trying to crack!)

[image]

Below is how my current header is

[image]

This is my current HTML, I also had to create a new CSS class for the brand so it would appear in the middle of the screen

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'>LOGO HERE</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FLAVOUR LAB</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">OUR STORY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VISIT US ON LIFE INVADER</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And the css is as follows

```
.navbar-brand {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
}
```

When I create a test image and try to apply the style i.e back ground image I get the following output, as you can see the logo with the curve half shows and appears to the left hand side of the screen.

[image]

The updated CSS

```
.navbar-brand {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
background-image: url('/Content/Images/TempLogoExample.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

I've attached a test Image for anyone that feels they want to have a go at it, any solution/advice would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears on the left corner because you have set `Left:0`. try changing that using percentage mark. Eg:- `left: 45%;`will work in your case. if not try changing the percentage value.

Comment: I've applied the 45% which has shuffled it over, but I still only see half of the image? how can I bring it over the top of the nav

Comment: Try this
.navbar {
    position: relative;
}
.navbar-brand{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px !important;  /* 50% of your logo width */
    display: block;
}

Answer (score 0):

I Recommend to go with a different markup approach to achieve this. Why can't you use columns grid in the main section and then bring your designs internally. Below markup will help you to acheive this.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FLAVOUR LAB</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'>LOGO HERE</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">OUR STORY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">VISIT US ON LIFE INVADER</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```